# "Delete word forward" in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard

I know that in bash, `alt-backspae` does what `ctrl-backspace` does in modern GUIs: It deletes a word backwards.

I'm looking for the equivalent of `ctrl-delete`, i.e. delete a word forward. I tried `alt-delete` but no luck. Does there exist a keyboard combination for this in Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>: delete word forward

This page might help you: http://xahlee.info/linux/bash_keybinding.html